# "No Boot Device Found" error on new laptop

Tags: system-installation

I just bought a new Acer Aspire E1 laptop and i have the following problem : 
i made a bootable USB with ubuntu 14.10 but after installation is finished i get the "No boot device" thingy. Can someone please explain what is needed to be done in order to make ubuntu work ?

Comment: See this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256083&p=13203044#post13203044 And it seems you have to set a password (never lose that) to unlock UEFI settings: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253311

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem before during an Ubuntu installation, just as you are having. Late in the installation, after Grub had installed, it said a reboot was necessary. So I manually rebooted the machine and that basically voided the installation because it was not actually finished yet. I repeated the installation and allowed the machine to reboot automatically and then everything worked.

I hope this helps!